# How to get the latest row by date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have an existing query that displays data like this:

```
NAME     COURSE   PROF    LASTUPDATE
NAME_1   MATH1    PROF_A  2015-10-14 09:55:26.637
NAME_2   ENG1     PROF_B  2015-10-14 09:54:07.087
NAME_2   ENG1     PROF_C  2015-10-14 10:02:31.663 
NAME_3   SOC1     PROF_D  2015-10-14 09:53:28.253 
NAME_4   PHL1     PROF_E  2015-10-14 09:55:47.293
NAME_3   SOC1     PROF_F  2015-10-14 09:59:00.000
```

I want to only select the latest rows (in terms of lastupdate) with the same name and course? The resulting table should be like this:

```
NAME     COURSE   PROF    LASTUPDATE
NAME_1   MATH1    PROF_A  2015-10-14 09:55:26.637
NAME_2   ENG1     PROF_C  2015-10-14 10:02:31.663  
NAME_4   PHL1     PROF_E  2015-10-14 09:55:47.293
NAME_3   SOC1     PROF_F  2015-10-14 09:59:00.000
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, course order by lastupdate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @sgeddes . . . "with the same name **and course**" (my highlight).  Thanks.

Comment: Another question though. I'm going to apply this on an existing query that uses "with CTE". That's where I'm going to get my "FROM". It will be like: SELECT T.* FROM (with CTE (...)) T. However, I'm getting an error that says incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. Is there a way to possibly integrate the query you suggested on my existing query?

Comment: @MarcusL. . . . You should ask another question with your actual query (or a reasonable simplification) in it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's okay. I integrated your query now. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

try first_value

```
select
first_value(last_update) over (partition by name_2 order by last_update DESC) as last_update 
from my_table;
```